# Split String in dataframe and Assign new string to new row in Dataframe (Opposite of toString() )

Tags: r

I am looking to split up a string into separate rows in a data frame and I'm not sure what the best approach would be. If I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
Gene=c("Gene1","Gene2", "Gene3")
Alt=c("ABC, DEF", "XYZ", "ABC, XYZ")
df=data.frame(Gene, Alt)
```

And the goal would be to split out the string to separate rows in the database such that the data frame assigns the split to the next row in the data frame and looks like this:

```
Gene.b=c("Gene1", "Gene1", "Gene2", "Gene3", "Gene3")
Alt.b=c("ABC","DEF","XYZ","ABC","XYZ")
df2=data.frame(Gene.b, Alt.b)
```

I tried using different approaches with stringr but couldn't seem to split them in a way to assign correctly to the associated gene. I'm looking for an operation that is sort of the opposite of the toString() function.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't see this in my searches. My question (and the answer provided) is a bit simpler in scope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We use `separate_rows` from `tidyr` and change the column names with `rename_all`

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
separate_rows(df, Alt) %>%
    rename_all(~ paste0(., '.b'))
```

Comment: This is great. Thanks. There were some other weird characters in my df (namely '_') and it performed a greedy separation so I added a sep parameter (eg. separate_rows(df, Alt, sep=",") to get what I needed.